# Create type and initialize it at run-time

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Suppose I have `Dictionary` like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "Name" , "John Smith"},
            { "Age", "34"}
        };
```

Now I want to create type from that dictionary and initialize it with values in run-time so that I was able to access it's properties with reflection.

For this example I want object with property `Name` equals to `"Jon Smith"` and `Age` equals to `34`.

*Edit:*
I need this to compare two objects with semantic comparison library such as [TestApi](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2010/07/29/10043968.aspx).   First object created by other code that has strong type

```
class Person 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age { get; set;}
}
```

and other I need to create from other source like xml file (but not necessary). Types that would be compared are known only in run-time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using C# 4 you could use `dynamic` and [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) for this - it's not *actually* creating a new type, but it's close enough in some cases:

```
IDictionary<string, object> foo = new ExpandoObject();
foreach (var pair in values)
{
    foo[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
}

dynamic d = foo;
string name = d.Name;
string age = d.Age; // This will still be a string, not an int
```

EDIT: I missed that you wanted to access the data with reflection. Using reflection is a way of effectively treating the type like a map - and you've already *got* it in that form. Why not just access the dictionary directly? The only benefit would be if you wanted to be able to use *some* types with reflection, and some with a dictionary. In that case I'd create a general-purpose interface with two implementations - one of which got values from a dictionary, and one of which used reflection. That's going to be a lot easier than creating a type on the fly (which is possible, but not a lot of fun).

Comment: But i can't access this property with reflection

Comment: @Orsol: No, you can't - sorry, I missed that bit before. But if you're using reflection already, why don't you just use the dictionary directly? Why bother going through a separate type?

Comment: @Jon: Sorry, my question was vague, I added some specific requirements

Comment: @Orsol: Have you considered implementing an appropriate ObjectComparer? Creating your own types on the fly really is going to get messy quickly.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Also, I need to display it in UI, so ObjectComparer will solve only part of problem

Comment: @Orsol: Again, if you hide the differences in an interface implemented in two different ways (either with reflection or a dictionary) that needn't be a problem.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:but I don't know structure of object that would be compared. It would be provided by user

Comment: @Orsol: Your interface would allow you to explore that though - you could ask it what properties are available. Really, you *don't* want to be building a new type on the fly just to access it with reflection.